# Can you provide a dataset (of n=50) where Kendall's Tau is greater than Spearman's Rho by at least 0.45?

Tags: spearman-rho, kendall-tau

That means that:

> τ(x,y) > ρ(x,y) + 0.45

I find it very hard to generate this dataset since if there's a linear correlation
in the data - it will probably show up if we use any of the correlation coefficients.

Comment: It's possible to do this, yes. How does the issue arise; is this for an assignment/class work?

Comment: If you lack intuition about how to make τ considerably larger than ρ, I suggest investigating all possible arrangements of 4 and 6 points for y vs a sorted x (this easy enough to do in R, say) and then noticing the pattern that maximizes τ(x,y) - ρ(x,y). That should give sufficient intuition to anticipate how to do it at larger sample sizes. This largest difference will increase as you increase n and exceeds 0.45 by n=20.

Comment: A forthcoming answer to the first question I asked will be likely to produce additional information.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, it is for an assignment

Comment: Did you try investigating the possible rank-orderings for 4 values -- that is, fix x=(1,2,3,4) and try all the permutations of 1,2,3 and 4 for y, computing the Spearman and Kendall correlation for each? Did you notice the shape of the arrangement with the largest $\tau-\rho$?

Comment: I have but never reached more than a 0.25 difference between the correlations

Comment: I have a difference of 4/15 (~0.267) at n=4, of 12/35 (~0.343) at n=6, of 24/63 at n=8 (~0.381), of 40/99 (~0.404) at n=10, and so on. You appear to have not considered all the possibilities

Comment: The particular arrangements that I found that maximize the difference (we only need worry about even $n$ for this) lead to a $\tau$ that approaches $0$ at large $n$ and a $\rho_{_S}$ that approaches $-\frac12$ at large $n$. Note that there are $24$ orderings of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Which ones did you consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer for future generations:

```py
    x = np.arange(1,51)
    y = np.arange(1,31) * 1000
    y = np.append(y, np.arange(1,21))
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y})
    print(df)
   
    spearman_rho = st.spearmanr(x, y)
    kendall_tau = st.kendalltau(x, y)
    
    print(f"spearman rho: {spearman_rho[0]}")
    print(f"Kendall tau: {kendall_tau[0]}")
    print(f"The difference between rho and tau: {spearman_rho[0] - kendall_tau[0]}")
    
    ax = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y)
    ax.set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
    plt.show()
```

output:

```
    x      y
0    1   1000
1    2   2000
2    3   3000
3    4   4000
4    5   5000
5    6   6000
6    7   7000
7    8   8000
8    9   9000
9   10  10000
10  11  11000
11  12  12000
12  13  13000
13  14  14000
14  15  15000
15  16  16000
16  17  17000
17  18  18000
18  19  19000
19  20  20000
20  21  21000
21  22  22000
22  23  23000
23  24  24000
24  25  25000
25  26  26000
26  27  27000
27  28  28000
28  29  29000
29  30  30000
30  31      1
31  32      2
32  33      3
33  34      4
34  35      5
35  36      6
36  37      7
37  38      8
38  39      9
39  40     10
40  41     11
41  42     12
42  43     13
43  44     14
44  45     15
45  46     16
46  47     17
47  48     18
48  49     19
49  50     20


spearman rho: -0.4405762304921968

Kendall tau: 0.020408163265306124

The difference between rho and tau: -0.46098439375750294
```

[image: plot]

Comment: For the benefit of those not using python, could you also include the output of your code?  and maybe even a plot?